# how maintain html page style while converting into word document?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an invoice page. I am trying to convert it into a word doc. It is converted into word doc but it does not maintain page css. here is my code.

```
function Export2Word(element, filename = ''){
    var preHtml = "<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'><head><meta charset='utf-8'><title>Export HTML To Doc</title><style>{table{page-break-inside:auto}tr{page-break-inside:avoid;page-break-after:auto}thead{display:table-header-group}tfoot{display:table-footer-group}}.Quotation-box{width:100%;border:1px solid #eee;background-color:#fff}table{border:1px solid #000;width:100%}.Quotation-box table td{padding:3px;vertical-align:top;}.right-border{border-right:1px solid #000;}.paddingcell{padding:5px;margin-bottom:6px;}.paddingcell1{padding:5px;margin-bottom:0}.bottom-border{border-bottom:1px solid #000;}.prod-title th{border-right:1px solid #000;}img{width:793px; height:auto;}.proddesc th{border-top:1px solid #000;}.terms{border-top:1px solid;}.calculation{padding:5px;}.fill{background:#80808078;}.print-btn{margin-bottom:5px;}.terms-condition{font-weight:700;border-bottom:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;background:#80808078;margin-bottom:0;border-right:1px solid #000;}.stamp-section{margin-top:150px;text-align:center;}.bank-div p{margin-bottom:2px;}.terms-div p{margin-bottom:3px;}.subth{width:400px;border-right:1px solid #000;padding:5px;font-weight:400;border-bottom:1px solid #000;}.subth1{width:250px;}@page{margin:3.5mm;}td{width:40px;}</style></head><body>";
    var postHtml = "</body></html>";
    var html = preHtml+document.getElementById(element).innerHTML+postHtml;

    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', html], {
        type: 'application/msword'
    });
    
    // Specify link url
    var url = 'data:application/vnd.ms-word;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html);
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.doc':'document.doc';
    
    // Create download link element
    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob ){
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = url;
        
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
    
    document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
}
```

Comment: Maybe this is usefull: [savetoDoc js](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/c24afe30a1adb685eb184b6b1a2fe5d9)

Comment: but i want my html page css

Comment: You want your page `css` automatically used for the `.doc`?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: Then you have to provide the `css` to the service you use. [savetoDoc.js](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/c24afe30a1adb685eb184b6b1a2fe5d9) can't use your pages css, but you can provide the same source for both.